# Proving that $\zeta(2)$ is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, zeta-functions

We have the following integral:
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1 P_n(x)\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx = \frac{a_n\zeta(2)+b_n}{d_n^2}
\end{align}
$P_n(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and degree $n$. $a_n,b_n$ are integers and $d_n$ is the less common multiple of all consecutive natural numbers up to $n$, so, $d_n^2=$ LCM$(1,2,...,n)^2$.

Since,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-ay}dy=-\frac{\ln (1-a)}{a}
\end{align}

we can use $a=1-x$ to have
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1 P_n(x)\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx &= 
-\int_0^1\int_0^1 P_n(x)\frac{1}{1-(1-x)y}dxdy\\
&=\frac{a_n\zeta(2)+b_n}{d_n^2}
\end{align}

now it's easier to integrate $I_n$ by parts $n$ times.

> Is there a polynomial $P_n(x)$ with integer coefficients and degree
>   $n$ such that $I_n d_n^2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty\:?$

I'm using this estimation: $d_n^2<e^{2An}$ for some real $A>1$.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx= -\sum_{k=0}^n c_k(\zeta(2)-\sum_{l=1}^{k} l^{-2})$. Then what ?